# Spring 3.0 MVC mvc:view-controller tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here's a snippet of my mvc-config.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<mvc:view-controller path="/index" view-name="welcome"/>    
<mvc:view-controller path="/static/login" view-name="/static/login"/>   
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="/static/login"/>
```

I have the welcome.jsp on /WEB-INF/view/ directory and login.jsp on /WEB-INF/view/static/.

This works for '/index' and '/login' paths. But I'm getting 404 response for '/static/login' when invoked from the browser. I'm expecting that '/static/login/' and '/login' should behave the same.

What could be wrong here?

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Here's the web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Enables clean URLs with JSP views e.g. /welcome instead of /app/welcome -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Maps all /app requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and here is the urlrewrite.xml:

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
    <rule>
        <from>/</from>
        <to>/app/welcome</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/static/**</from>
        <to last="true">/static/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/**</from>
        <to last="true">/app/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <outbound-rule>
        <from>/app/**</from>
        <to>/$1</to>
    </outbound-rule>    
</urlrewrite>
```

Environment: 
I'm using SpringSource tc Server Dev Edition v2.0
Spring version: 3.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Request for `/static/login` can't get into your DispatcherServlet, because it matches the rewriting rule from `/static/**` to `/static/$1` with `last = "true"`, and therefore doesn't match the rule from `/**` to `/app/$1`, which leads to DispatcherServlet. See [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) docs for more info.

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine for me, can you tell me what is your Dispatcher Servlet mappings? It would be nice if you can attach the entire web.xml content.

Comment: I've edited my question to include web.xml content and urlrewrite.xml. Thanks!